# Warning: require_once error

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(include/DB_Functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\android_login_api\register.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'include/DB_Functions.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\android_login_api\register.php on line 3
```

It's because this line of code:

```
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
```

Here is a screenshot of how my folder structure looks like link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMC7n.png

**What have I tried?**

The most obviously thing that I had tried was doing this in the register.php file:

```
require_once '../include/DB_Functions.php';
```

Comment: According to your screenshot, the file is `DB_Functons.php` - you've misstyped the name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DB_Functions.php is misspelled on your server.

Answer (score 3):

Your file is called DB_Functons.php